# Why SpringApplication load ApplicationContextInitializer by config?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm reading source code of `SpringApplication.java`. I fount it load `ApplicationContextInitializer` and `ApplicationListener` in a complex way:

```
private <T> Collection<? extends T> getSpringFactoriesInstances(Class<T> type,
        Class<?>[] parameterTypes, Object... args) {
    ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    // Use names and ensure unique to protect against duplicates
    Set<String> names = new LinkedHashSet<String>(
            SpringFactoriesLoader.loadFactoryNames(type, classLoader));
    List<T> instances = createSpringFactoriesInstances(type, parameterTypes,
            classLoader, args, names);
    AnnotationAwareOrderComparator.sort(instances);
    return instances;
}
```

Why not just create these factory instances by `new` key word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default scope for Spring beans is always singleton. Spring Singleton is unique within context or container. For example, in your example it seems to be one instance per context:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
// Use names and ensure unique to protect against duplicates
Set<String> names = new LinkedHashSet<String>(
                SpringFactoriesLoader.loadFactoryNames(type, classLoader));
List<T> instances = createSpringFactoriesInstances(type, parameterTypes,
                classLoader, args, names);
```

The last line:

```
AnnotationAwareOrderComparator.sort(instances);
```

as I suppose, orders instances for loading:

> The order of creation is important for Spring. After digesting the
>   configuration metadata, Spring creates a plan (it allocates certain
>   priorities to each bean) with the order of beans that needs to be
>   created to satisfy dependencies.

And the reason why it is namely `AnnotationAwareOrderComparator` is that annotation-based ordering is supported for many kinds of components in Spring. 
For example ([section 44.2](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html)):

> You can use the @AutoConfigureAfter or @AutoConfigureBefore
>   annotations if your configuration needs to be applied in a specific
>   order.

Comment: Thanks. I did find `commonClassCache` in the load method.

Answer (score 1):

I think reason behind it is loose coupling, and reusability, ApplicationContextInitializer is interface and there are many classes present in spring application like AutoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer,ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer,ContextCustomizerAdapter and many more which are implementing the ApplicationContextInitializer,
So if they used new keyword so it was tightly coupling which is breaking own spring principle(loosed coupling, dependency injection).

Comment: Thanks. I understand loose coupling and reusability, but I do not agree this is the behind reason using config not `new`.